# Difference between "zukunftsweisend" and "zukunftsorientiert"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, vocabulary

"**zukunftsweisend**" means *forward-looking, trend-setting*, while "**zukunftsorientiert**" implies *future-oriented*.

I can more or less feel the difference: products of "**zukunftsweisend**" help actively shape the future; products of "**zukunftsorientiert**" simply means accomodating whatever could happen in the future (mostly passive). Is it correct?

In addition, what makes this issue more interesting is "**zukunftsweisend**" is of Partizip I, and "**zukunftsorientiert**" is of Partizip II. In English, we have similiar structure: interesting vs. interested. Why not use "**zukunftsorientierend**"?

Comment: > Is it correct? 
I agree with you. "Zukunftsorientiert" can simply be passive, while "-weisend" has an influence or is thought to have an influence.  
For the participles, that can be easily seen in its meaning. Participle 2 implies that current influence is done, while participle 1 describes a property of someone.

Answer (score 1):

Your distinction and deduction for the difference is correct.

Why not 'zukunftsorientierend'? An attempt to explain or reason: You cannot orient the future (as a whole). You can try point or nudge it in a direction when it asks where it should go. While it thus may take your advice, it chooses it's own path, considering and weighing many inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The verb *weisen* strongly demands a direction, and that is inherited by the adjective *zukunftsweisend*.

> zukunftsweisend — **Wohin** weist es? **In die Zukunft.**

You could argue the same for the verb *sich orientieren* but it's not used that way. The usual adverbial that goes with it is who helps with the orientation. E.g. a map, the sun, a compass etc. Not a direction. Again, this property of the verb is inherited by the adjective *zukunftsorientiert*.

> zukunftsorientiert — **Woran** orientiert es sich? **An der Zukunft.**

That one is built from the active Partizip I while the other is built from the passive Partizip II is a coincidence. Your proposed *zukunftsorientierend* makes little sense to me however because it would require that *Zukunft* is actively orientienting itself because the verb is reflexive.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is due to the two different verbs from which the adjectives are derived: [*weisen*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/weisen) and [*orientieren*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/orientieren) are two different actions.

"Etwas(1) an etwas(2) orientieren" *(to orient something to(wards) something)* means to set the direction or place of something(1) to align it with a direction or a position(2). It's a placement or movement, something is being moved or changing direction.

"Irgendwohin weisen", in contrast, is static, it means to point somewhere. A ["Wegweiser"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/wegweiser) is a signpost that points in a certain direction, it *has been oriented* in that direction by someone in the know when it was put up, but its use now is to show a direction to people.

So something can be "zukunftsorientiert" which means it *has been set* to point toward the direction where someone thought the future lies, it *has been oriented* toward the future, thats why it's a Partizip II.

Or it can be "zukunftsweisend" which means it *is showing* people where the future might be, active, but static. That's why it's Partizip I.